# How to set RowFilter case-insensitive for DataView

Tags: c#, sql, case-insensitive, dataview, rowfilter

I have a datagrid, its datasource is a dataview.  There is a textbox with which users can type in filter text. I want to make the filter to be case insensitive.
say, the typed text is "Tg"

I tried this

```
Mydataview.RowFilter = "UPPER(COL) LIKE '%TG%'"
```

but this gives me an invalidoperation exception

then I changed it to

```
Mydataview.RowFilter = "COL LIKE '%tg%' or COL LIKE '%TG%'"
```

This works but it does not cover all cases. E.g. If a row is "Tg", it will be filtered out which is not desirable. 
What I want, when users type "Tg", it will match any data with tg, Tg, TG, tG, all the combination

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`RowFilter` obeys dataset `CaseSensitive` value

So do this in your Form_Load method:

`CaseSensitive` is set to `False` by default

```
mydataset.CaseSensitive = false
```

Proof of concept:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not use dataset, I use a datatable, I tried set MyTable.CaseSensitive = false, does not work

Comment: Why don't you write all possible combinations: "COL LIKE '%tg%' or COL LIKE '%TG%' or COL LIKE '%Tg%' or COL LIKE '%tG%'"

Comment: That's so long (though possible). If users type in "test", then I have 16 combinations.  I try to avoid this if possible.  thanks

Comment: thanks, I just tried with datatable, it works. I made a mistake when I tried previously.

Comment: Although I suppose there could be conditions where you want it, so this setting might have to be changed in those places if the dataset is reused....

Answer (score -1):

select the name twice with one of them being upper(name) as finder and then use that column (non visable) to filter your rows